# output shape of STFT

Tags: fourier-transform, stft, eeg

I cant figure out why our output image is 257 * 32 , 32 I know why , but 257 I cant understand ? this is the exact word of [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27900952) wich applied STFT on 3 channel of eeg signal :

Short time Fourier transform (STFT) was applied on the
time series for each 2 s long trial. In case of 250 Hz signal this
is corresponding to 500 samples. STFT was performed with
window size equal to 64 and time lapses equal to 14. Starting
from sample 1 toward sample 500, STFT is computed for 32
windows over 498 samples and the last 2 samples, remaining
at the end, are simply ignored. This leads to a 257   ×   32 image
where 257 and 32 are the number of samples along the frequency and time axes respectively.

I really really appreciated if anyone could explain it to me

Comment: There must be a mistake. 257 points to a window length of 512 with the spectrum being one sided.

Comment: Overlap window.